# Add all product variant and quantity to the cart with AJAX in Shopify store

Tags: javascript, ajax, shopify, liquid

In my Shopify store on the product page I have a table with variant title, price and input quantity column. Could I added to the cart all input quantity for each variants of the product with AJAX ?

my table:

```
<form action="/cart/add" method="post" >

 <tr>
   {% for variant in product.variants %}
 {% assign variant = product.selected_or_first_available_variant %}
     <td>{{ variant.title }}</td>
     <td>{{ variant.price | money }}</td>
     <td>  
       <input name="quantity" inputmode="numeric" value="0">
     </td>
   {% endfor %}
 </tr>

<input type="submit" value="Add to cart">
</form>



<script>
let addToCartForm = document.querySelector('form[action="/cart/add"]');
let formData = new FormData(addToCartForm);
 fetch('/cart/add.js', {
   method: 'POST',
   body: formData
 })
 .then(response => {
   return response.json();
 })
 .catch((error) => {
   console.error('Error:', error);
});
</script>
```

And some Shopify documentation
https://shopify.dev/api/ajax/reference/cart#post-cart-add-js

I'm trying added to cart all product variants for one call with AJAX and get:

**Required parameter missing or invalid: items**

Comment: Can you please provide a bit more detail about what exactly isn't working?  (Is the problem with the quantity selectors, or are the quantity values not being read properly by Shopify when you try to submit them?) Can you please also add your code to this question as a code block rather than as a link to a picture of code? If the problem is with the submit, can you also please expand the selection to include any `<form>` tag wrapping the table?  If the form is being submitted using Javascript, the JS code associated with the add-to-cart action could also be helpful.  :)

Comment: Thanks, It's my first steps in JS and Shopify and on stackoverflow also :)

Answer (score 1):

**Summary:** Your form submission contains quantities but no products. You need to include the variant IDs as well.

---

In your for-loop, you have created quantity boxes for all of the variants in the product but are missing the variant IDs. When you post that data to `/cart/add.js`, Shopify has no way to know which products you're trying to put in the cart.

For adding multiple items in the cart at once, I would recommend taking a look at Shopify's documentation for the Cart API: https://shopify.dev/api/ajax/reference/cart#post-cart-add-js

To add multiple items to the cart, we need to submit a field called `items` as an array of objects specifying the IDs to add and optionally their quantities and any line-item properties we are attaching.

Here's a quick thought on how the resulting code might look:

```
<form class="custom-product-form" action="/cart/add" method="post">
  <table>
   {% for variant in product.variants %}
   <tr>
     <td>{{ variant.title }}</td>
     <td>{{ variant.price | money }}</td>
     <td class="item-submission">
       <!-- Added hidden input for the variant ID -->
       <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ variant.id }}"/>
       <input name="quantity" inputmode="numeric" value="0">
     </td>
   </tr>
   {% endfor %}
  </table>
  <input type="submit" value="Add to cart">
</form>

<script>
  let addToCartForm = document.querySelector('.custom-product-form');
  addToCartForm.addEventListener('submit', (evt) => {
    evt.preventDefault();
    // Update to create an object based on the multiple input rows
    let items = [];
    let rows = evt.currentTarget.querySelectorAll('.item-submission');

    for(let i=0; i<rows.length; i++) {
      // Get the variant ID and quantity for each row. 
      let itemData = rows[i];
      let id = parseInt(itemData.querySelector('[name="id"]').value );
      let qty = parseInt(itemData.querySelector('[name="quantity"]').value );
      // We don't care about any rows with a quantity of 0
      if(id && qty > 0){
        items.push({ id: id, quantity: qty });
      }
    }
    if(!items.length){
      // Do something to tell the customer that there's nothing to add if all quantities were 0
      return;
    }

    return fetch('/cart/add.js', {
       method: 'POST',
       body: JSON.stringify({ items: items }),
       headers: { 'Content-type': 'application/json' },
       credentials: 'include' 
       // Note: Including credentials sends the cart cookie, which is important to make sure that the items go into the shopper's cart and not into a void
     })
     .then(response => {
       return response.json();
     })
     .catch((error) => {
       console.error('Error:', error);
    });
  })
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications. Now another issue came up - after I click "add to cart" button nothing is changing and I get the following in the console: 
**Cannot read properties of null (reading 'value') at HTMLFormElement**

Comment: Hmm... I just free-handed the code so may have missed or misspelled something.  I'm taking a look to see if I missed something...

Comment: I made a small edit and it works on my test store when I run it - Give it another try and let me know if it's working or not on your side :)

Comment: Yes, now it's work correct. Thank you so much for your support!

Comment: Huzzah!  Best of luck with your project :)